# How to filter which attributes I want to delete in Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are certain attributes from the class I allow to be deleted. But, others are forbidden to be deleted.

```
class klass:
    a = 1
    b = 2

    def __delattr__(cls, attr):
        if attr=='a':
            pass # go ahead, delete attribute a
        elif attr=='b':
            raise TypeError("Bad boy/girl, you shouldn't delete attribute b")

del klass.a
del klass.b
```

This code does not work. What's wrong with the code? Both attributes are still being deleted. I am using Python 3 by the way. `__delattr__` does not seem to work. Please note, I don't want to instantiate the class (I don't want `foo = klass(); del foo.a;` / I want `del klass.a;`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. This answer is based on the answers from Ashwini Chaudhary and NPE. I upvoted both of you! Thanks again.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __delattr__(cls, attr):
        if attr=='b':
            raise TypeError("Bad boy/girl, you shouldn't delete attribute b")
        elif attr=='a':
            super(Meta, cls).__delattr__(attr)

class klass(metaclass=Meta):
    a = 1
    b = 2

print(hasattr(klass, 'a'))  # True
del klass.a
print(hasattr(klass, 'a'))  # False
del klass.b  # throws TypeError exception
```

Answer (score 6):

`__delattr__()` deals with the deletion of attributes of class *instances*. Your code attempts to delete attributes *of the class itself*.

The following works as expected:

```
class klass(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.a = 1
      self.b = 2

   def __delattr__(self, attr):
      if attr == 'b':
         raise TypeError("Bad boy/girl, you shouldn't delete attribute b")
      else:
         super(klass, self).__delattr__(attr)

k = klass()
del k.a
del k.b
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the explanation. So how do I deal with the attributes of the class itself, not the instance?

Comment: @vajrasky: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? I sense there might be a little be of the XY problem going on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I am hacking Enum class (in Python 3.4, Lib/enum.py). For example: "from enum import Enum\nclass klass(Enum):\n  red = 1\n  def spam(cls): pass\n" del klass.red will throws AttributeError instead of TypeError. So I intercept it with __delattr__ inside EnumMeta class and raise TypeError. It works. But the problem is the spam function cannot be deleted any more. I don't know how to delete spam function inside __delattr__.

Comment: In case you are wondering why I asked this question: http://bugs.python.org/issue19025

Answer (score 1):

Use a metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):
   _a = 1
   @property
   def a(self):
      return self._a

   @a.setter
   def a(self, value):
       self._a = value

class klass(metaclass=Meta):
    b = 2
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> klass.a, klass.b
(1, 2)
>>> del klass.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-22-b06d010031d5>", line 1, in <module>
    del klass.a
AttributeError: can't delete attribute

>>> del klass.b
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I have a question, if you will. Suppose I can not control the generation of klass class (it is generated by the user). I want to make sure if they create a class klass with metaclass Meta with attribute a, they can delete the attribute. But if they create a class klass with metaclass Meta with attribute b, they can *not* delete the attribute, can I enforce that in Meta class? I can intercept the deletion by creating __delattr__ in the meta class. I can filter them by the argument. I can prevent the deletion by raising the exception. I don't know how to delete the attr